# wordpress : hungryfeed not showing title nor image but shows date and content

Tags: wordpress, feed

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this (please, point me to the right place if not).
I am using hungryfeed in a wordpress website and it just shows the date and content, no title nor image. how can i show the title of each article and image. [show_data](http://pastebin.com/NgpXyf8K) array is not empty.

I tried: `{{data[attribs]['child']['']['title'][0]['data']}}` to print the title without success in the template.
Which files should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got the title to display on template 1:

```
<div  class="hungryfeed_item">
    <div>Posted: {{post_date}}</div>
    <div class="feed_image">{{image}}<a href ="{{permalink}}" ></a>
    <div><a href="{{permalink}}">{{data['child']['']['title']['0']['data']}}</a></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps someone.